# No entiendo porque lanza este error en mi codigo

Tags: python, numpy

Cuando compilo mi codigo me lanza el siguiente error:

```
line 23, in comprar
    if(edificio[piso][tipo] == 0):
IndexError: only integers, slices (:), ellipsis (...), numpy.newaxis (None) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

Este es mi codigo:

```
edificio = np.zeros([10,4],dtype= object)
run = np.zeros([10,4],dtype= object)

def comprar():

    print(edificio)
    piso = int(input("Seleccione piso:"))
    while(piso > 10):
        print("Error, vuelva a ingrear un piso")
        piso = input("Piso:")
    tipo = input("Seleccione tipo(Mayúscula):")
    while(tipo != "A" and tipo != "B" and tipo != "C" and tipo != "D"):
        print("Error, vuelva a ingresar un tipo de departamento")
        tipo = input("Tipo(Mayuscula):")
    if(edificio[piso][tipo] == 0):     # **<-- linea 23, donde esta el error**
        rut = input("Ingrese su rut sin dígito verificador:")
        edificio[piso][tipo] = X
        run[piso][tipo] = rut
```

Answer (score 1):

edit: 
entiendo que tu problema es que estas poniendo una letra en tipo y te esta diciendo que solo acepta numeros. 
proba definiendo tipo como numeros tambien en vez de letras y fijate si funciona

Intenta poner el codigo para que se lea mas claro con los {} que figura.

```
print ("asi podemos leer algo asi")
```

Saludos!

Comment: fue rapido para que me entienda jeje, eso es una mezcla entre java y c ponele..

Comment: me funciono, muchas gracias.

Comment: @matnalopez El código de ejemplo que pones no es útil en esta pregunta, pues, además de no guardar relación con la solución propuesta, la pregunta era sobre Python, lenguaje que no usa llaves para delimitar bloques. Mejor quitas esa observación y dejas sólo la parte que resuelve el problema.

Comment: Si te funciono no olvides marcarla como respuesta, de esa forma ayudas a otras personas que presenten el mismo problema.

Comment: @abulafia listo, editado para que el print este en Python! aun que ayer lo habiamos borrado directamente, no entiendo por que volvio a aparecer nuevamente. Gracias por explicar!